# Catching the exit event of a simple console application

Tags: delphi, events, console, exit

I have this simple console application in Delphi 2010 and I would like it to do something (run a piece of code) when I press the "X" button (when I close it), however I can't seem to find how to assign a close event to it. Neep help, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [SetConsoleCtrlHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686016%28VS.85%29.aspx) Windows API function to set your handler.

Comment: Keep in mind that the handler function executes in a separate thread, *not* in the console program's main thread.

Comment: @Rob this is written in the top of description of the handler function in MSDN. Yet 1 vote for the comment anyway :).